# Grub2 with Kali, how to boot into Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, multi-boot, grub, kali-linux

I will preface this with saying I am new to linux. I had windows 7 installed on my main SSD, I wanted to give Kali a try so I installed that on a 2nd SSD. When the option to install grub2 came up, having used Ubuntu before, I installed that on my main SSD. I now can not boot into windows. I tried `sudo update-grub2` and that gave me:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.0-kali3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.18.0-kali3-amd64
No volume groups found
```

I ran bootinfoscript and that gave me:

```
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of the same
hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks for (,msdos1)/boot/grub
on this drive.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or sda1 busy

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

Drive/Partition info:

```
Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   239,855,615   239,853,568  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         239,857,662   250,068,991    10,211,330   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         239,857,664   250,068,991    10,211,328  82 Linux swap / Solaris

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 512.1 GB, 512110190592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 62260 cylinders, total 1000215216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1               2,048 1,000,212,479 1,000,210,432   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
```

"blkid" output:

```
Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        6cb27243-ec3c-45c8-a66d-7316fb1db39c   ext4       
/dev/sda5        e9e1f9dc-7998-4ec7-b8a2-36c7bf60906a   swap       
/dev/sdb1        2A0CBB1D0CBAE34D                       ntfs
```

Mount points:

```
Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/disk/by-uuid/6cb27243-ec3c-45c8-a66d-7316fb1db39c /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive:

```
sdc
```

StdErr messages:

```
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
No volume groups found
```

I have no idea how boot back into my windows 7. Thanks in advance for the help. Let me know if any other info is needed.

Edit 1:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

AND

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6cb27243-ec3c-45c8-a66d-7316fb1db39c
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=640x480
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6cb27243-ec3c-45c8-a66d-7316fb1db39c
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
set timeout=5
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6cb27243-ec3c-45c8-a66d-7316fb1db39c
insmod png
if background_image /usr/share/images/desktop-base/kali-grub.png; then
  set color_normal=white/black
  set color_highlight=black/white
else
  set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
  set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.18.0-kali3-amd64' --class kali --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6cb27243-ec3c-45c8-a66d-7316fb1db39c
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.0-kali3-amd64 root=UUID=6cb27243-ec3c-45c8-a66d-7316fb1db39c ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.18.0-kali3-amd64
}
menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class kali --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6cb27243-ec3c-45c8-a66d-7316fb1db39c
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.18.0-kali3-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.18.0-kali3-amd64 root=UUID=6cb27243-ec3c-45c8-a66d-7316fb1db39c ro single 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.18.0-kali3-amd64
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: when you installed linux on a second HD, you can try to change boot order in bios to boot up windows on first HD (when nothing else works)

Comment: Grub2 was installed on the same drive as Windows, windows isn't even getting a chance to boot.

Comment: care to share  the contents of  /etc/default/grub & /boot/grub2/grub.cfg ?

Comment: I added the contents of those.